# Not understanding for loop output

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

When using the 'a' variable the interpret function outputs the number 20 as I'd expect.

```
linkedin <- c(16, 9, 13, 5, 2, 17, 14)

interpret <- function(num_views) {
  if (num_views > 15) {
    print("You're popular!")
    return(num_views)
  } else {
    print("Try to be more visible!")
    return(0)
  }
}

a <- 20

interpret(a)
#[1] "You're popular!"
#[1] 20
```

Why then does the for loop not output the numbers above 15 and 0?

```
for (v in linkedin) {
     interpret(v)
}

#[1] "You're popular!"
#[1] "Try to be more visible!"
#[1] "Try to be more visible!"
#[1] "Try to be more visible!"
#[1] "Try to be more visible!"
#[1] "You're popular!"
#[1] "Try to be more visible!"
```

I'm running this on the datacamp website instead of the `R` software in case that makes a difference.

Comment: Please tag with the correct language and remove some empty lines: maybe you can get rid of the scrollbar

Comment: The above code works as expected, as far as I can tell. Note that executing `interpret(a)` on a per-line basis (Ctrl + Enter) will cause the function's output to print. Executing `interpret` as part of a `source` command, or even inside of a loop, will cause it to return silently. Inside your loop, try `print(interpret(v))`

Answer (score 0):

```
linkedin <- c(16, 9, 13, 5, 2, 17, 14)

interpret <- function(num_views) {
    if (num_views > 15) {
        print("You're popular!")
        print(num_views)
    } else {
        print("Try to be more visible!")
        print(0)
    }
}

a <- 20

interpret(a)

for (v in linkedin) {
    interpret(v)
}
```